# Apparent IRQ conflict driving me nuts under CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, xen, irq

**The Environment**

I have a small, dual-core Intel Atom-based server running CentOS 5.5 x64 with a slightly customized Xen kernel. It also has one on-board 10/100 NIC with an additional 3-port 10/100 NIC.  Within this server, I also run a single Xen domU which functions as a firewall, DHCP server, and caching DNS forwarder.  The domU is running CentOS 5.5 x64 as well, but with a stock Xen kernel.

I'm using the pciback kernel module to hide the 3-port NIC from the dom0 and assign it to my virtualized firewall.  Eth1 is my public interface and the on-board NIC (eth0) is my private interface, which is on a XEN bridge and shared between both the Dom0 and DomU.

**The Problem**

The problem is that eth1 (the public interface on my virtualized firewall) decides to stop working several times a day.  It seems to be related to usage:  if I barely run much traffic across that interface, it might last a couple days.  Heavy web browsing though will take it down in a couple hours.  When it dies, this is the error in /var/log/messages on my firewall:

```
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel: irq 18: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel: 
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel: Call Trace:
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff802b3d60>] __report_bad_irq+0x30/0x7d
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff802b3f97>] note_interrupt+0x1ea/0x22b
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff802b348f>] __do_IRQ+0xbd/0x103
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff80290319>] _local_bh_enable+0x61/0xc5
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff8026df48>] do_IRQ+0xe7/0xf5
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff803b3eca>] evtchn_do_upcall+0x13b/0x1fb
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff802608d6>] do_hypervisor_callback+0x1e/0x2c
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  <EOI>  [<ffffffff802063aa>] hypercall_page+0x3aa/0x1000
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff802063aa>] hypercall_page+0x3aa/0x1000
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff8026f4eb>] raw_safe_halt+0x84/0xa8
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff8024ad2e>] cpu_idle+0x4a/0xba
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff8026ca80>] xen_idle+0x38/0x4a
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff8024ad7b>] cpu_idle+0x97/0xba
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff8064cb0f>] start_kernel+0x21f/0x224
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel:  [<ffffffff8064c1e5>] _sinittext+0x1e5/0x1eb
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel: 
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel: handlers:
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel: [<ffffffff8811b8dd>] (rtl8139_interrupt+0x0/0x421 [8139too])
Jul 30 14:17:48 fw kernel: Disabling IRQ #18
Jul 30 14:18:02 fw kernel: NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth1: transmit timed out
Jul 30 14:18:05 fw kernel: eth1: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x41E1
Jul 30 14:18:17 fw kernel: NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth1: transmit timed out
Jul 30 14:18:20 fw kernel: eth1: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x41E1
Jul 30 14:18:32 fw kernel: NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth1: transmit timed out
```

I get a similar story in the Dom0's log. But as you can see, it completely disables the NIC's IRQ and shuts down the interface.

```
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel: irq 18: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel: 
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel: Call Trace:
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff802b3e13>] __report_bad_irq+0x30/0x7d
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  [<ffffffff802b404a>] note_interrupt+0x1ea/0x22b
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  [<ffffffff802b3542>] __do_IRQ+0xbd/0x103
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  [<ffffffff8029044e>] _local_bh_enable+0x61/0xc5
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  [<ffffffff8026df5a>] do_IRQ+0xe7/0xf5
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  [<ffffffff803b3993>] evtchn_do_upcall+0x13b/0x1fb
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  [<ffffffff802608d6>] do_hypervisor_callback+0x1e/0x2c
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  <EOI>  [<ffffffff802063aa>] hypercall_page+0x3aa/0x1000
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  [<ffffffff802063aa>] hypercall_page+0x3aa/0x1000
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  [<ffffffff8026f4fd>] raw_safe_halt+0x84/0xa8
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  [<ffffffff8026ca92>] xen_idle+0x38/0x4a
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  [<ffffffff8024b0b6>] cpu_idle+0x97/0xba
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  [<ffffffff8064cb0f>] start_kernel+0x21f/0x224
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel:  [<ffffffff8064c1e5>] _sinittext+0x1e5/0x1eb
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel: 
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel: handlers:
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel: [<ffffffff803e7b6c>] (usb_hcd_irq+0x0/0x55)
Jul 30 13:46:54 server kernel: Disabling IRQ #18
Jul 30 14:26:06 server kernel: xenbr0: port 3(vif1.0) entering disabled state
Jul 30 14:26:06 server kernel: device vif1.0 left promiscuous mode
Jul 30 14:26:06 server kernel: xenbr0: port 3(vif1.0) entering disabled state
Jul 30 14:26:06 server kernel: ACPI: PCI interrupt for device 0000:02:04.0 disabled
Jul 30 14:26:06 server kernel: ACPI: PCI interrupt for device 0000:02:06.0 disabled
Jul 30 14:26:06 server kernel: ACPI: PCI interrupt for device 0000:02:07.0 disabled
```

The obvious answer is to do what the error message suggests and boot with the "irqpoll" option.  However that has no affect, regardless of whether I boot the dom0 or the domU with "irqpoll".  Does anyone have any suggestions?  I'm getting somewhat desperate here...

**Additional Technical Details**

*Truncated "lspci -vv" output on dom0:*

```
02:04.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
        Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR-
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
        Region 0: I/O ports at de00 [disabled] [size=256]
        Region 1: Memory at fdeff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0-,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
```

*cat /proc/interrupts on dom0:*

```
           CPU0              CPU1              CPU2              CPU3              
  1:          8          0          0          0        Phys-irq  i8042
  4:         10          0          0          0        Phys-irq  serial
  8:          0          0          0          0        Phys-irq  rtc
  9:          0          0          0          0        Phys-irq  acpi
 12:          4          0          0          0        Phys-irq  i8042
 14:     162844          0       1910          0        Phys-irq  ata_piix
 15:          0          0          0          0        Phys-irq  ata_piix
 16:          0          0          0          0        Phys-irq  uhci_hcd:usb5
 17:          0          0          0          0        Phys-irq  uhci_hcd:usb3
 18:     200001          0          0          0        Phys-irq  uhci_hcd:usb4
 19:          2          0          0          0        Phys-irq  ehci_hcd:usb1, uhci_hcd:usb2
254:     515869          0          0         33        Phys-irq  peth0
256:   26214795          0          0          0     Dynamic-irq  timer0
257:      26047          0          0          0     Dynamic-irq  resched0
258:         54          0          0          0     Dynamic-irq  callfunc0
259:          0      15252          0          0     Dynamic-irq  resched1
260:          0        176          0          0     Dynamic-irq  callfunc1
261:          0     768956          0          0     Dynamic-irq  timer1
262:          0          0      96066          0     Dynamic-irq  resched2
263:          0          0        175          0     Dynamic-irq  callfunc2
264:          0          0    2193136          0     Dynamic-irq  timer2
265:          0          0          0      30317     Dynamic-irq  resched3
266:          0          0          0        132     Dynamic-irq  callfunc3
267:          0          0          0     904610     Dynamic-irq  timer3
268:        371          0        512          0     Dynamic-irq  xenbus
NMI:          0          0          0          0 
LOC:          0          0          0          0 
ERR:          0
```

*Truncated "/boot/grub/grub.conf" on dom0:*

```
title CentOS (2.6.18-194.3.1.el5.sb_iq1xen)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /xen.gz-2.6.18-194.3.1.el5.sb_iq1
        module /vmlinuz-2.6.18-194.3.1.el5.sb_iq1xen ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 xencons=off console=ttyS0,38400 irqpoll
        module /initrd-2.6.18-194.3.1.el5.sb_iq1xen.img
```

Comment: I've booted with the "nousb" kernel option to see what happens.  Doing so completely shuffled around the assigned IRQs and might eliminate the problems.  If it works though, it's more of a band aid solution since I'd hate to lose all USB functionality.

Comment: Are you sure the NICs aren't bad?  I've seen this error a few times over the years and it usually means that either the NIC is bad or the server is running into capacity issues (trying to send more than 100Mb worth of data constantly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a capacity issue haven't you thought about simply setting up a traffic shaping rule so that you're less likely to exceed the benchmark?

http://torrent-invites.com/seedbox-tutorials/80552-howto-implementing-bandwidth-quota-traffic-shaping-your-dedicated-seedbox.html